# Как добавить long long в название файла вывода?

Tags: c++

```
bool addAccount(long long num, long long arr[], int& size) {
  ofstream fout(num + ".txt");
  if(isNumberCorrect(num) == true)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == num)
        return false;
    }
    fout << 0;
    size++;
    arr[size-1] = num;
    return true;
  }else return false;
}
```

> ofstream fout(num + ".txt");

Как num сделать частью названия файла? (в таком виде конечно же не работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1 -

```
ofstream fout((to_string(num) + ".txt").c_str());
```

Вариант 2 -

```
char filename[40];
sprintf(filename,"%lld.txt",num);
ofstream fout(filename);
```

Достаточно? :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!